# Save the selections made in the qcombobox in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm new to Pyqt programming. i tried to build a simple GUI which looks like the one in the picture:

[image]

This is the code which i wrote:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import subprocess
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
     Ui_Dialog.hypermesh =0
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(435, 181)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
        self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(Dialog)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self.groupBox)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        hypmv=[]
        cont=subprocess.Popen('ls /usr/local/bin/hm*',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
        contents = cont.stdout.readlines()
        for i in range(len(contents)):
            temp=contents[i].strip()
            temp=temp.split('/')
            size=len(temp)
            hypmv.append(temp[size-1])
            self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
            self.comboBox.setItemText(i, _translate("Dialog", hypmv[i], None))
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")),self.hypm)
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Software Selector", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Hypermesh(Pre processor)", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Quit", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Save", None))
    def hypm(self):
        Ui_Dialog.hypermesh  = unicode(self.comboBox.currentText())
        subprocess.Popen(Ui_Dialog.hypermesh,shell=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the code the combobox items are intialized when the gui intializes and when i hit the button should open the software version which was selected in the combobox currently. this function it's doing pretty good.

But now i want to save the selection made by the user so that every time he invokes the gui he shouldn't select again the version previously he used in the combobox.

so if he selects hm_11.0 for the first time it should be everytime "hm_11.0" until he changes it. How can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the class you want to be reading: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsettings.html

There is like a small tutorial inside (ctrl+f Restoring the State of a GUI Application).

You will use setValue to store information with par keyToSetting/valueOfSetting and reading with value keyToSetting.

Example:
    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

```
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.readSettings()
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple')      

        self.show()

    def readSettings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings("AyaanTech", "SoftwareTest")
        self.setGeometry(settings.value("geometry", QtCore.QRect(300, 300, 250, 150)).toRect());

    def writeSettings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings("AyaanTech", "SoftwareTest")
        settings.setValue("geometry", self.geometry());

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        quit_msg = "Do you want to save position and size?"
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message', 
                     quit_msg, QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)

        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.writeSettings()
            event.accept()
        elif reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.No:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: i understood little bit of the reference can u give some examples if u have@Elric

Comment: Ok, created an example. Tell me what you don't understand. I couldn't run your code.